# How do I serialize a system type so I can store in viewstate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization

I have a property that is a `List<BaseValidator>`. I need to save this property in viewstate so it exists on postback. I get an error back to indicate that the list isn't serializable.

I've Googled ... and Googled but not got an answer that works yet.

I've also created my own custom class but I still get the error because BaseValidator isn't a simple type.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A list is serializable if the generic type is serializable. You should make the generic object and sub objects in your list serializable. Add the `[Serializable]` tag to these objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize arrays. So edit your class to contain an array property for your list. Set editor browsable to never so it doenst show up in Visual Studio and make your list nonserialized.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    //property for usage in code. dont serialize
    [NonSerialized]
    public List<BaseValidator> MyList { get; set; }

    // Property for serialization only
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public BaseValidator[] MyArray
    {
        get
        {
            return MyList.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            MyList = new List<BaseValidator>(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the list isn't serializable, you can always mark the class as `[Serializable]` and allow it to be stored in `ViewState`